# What does a red box mean in the work tab?

Tags: rimworld

In Rim World, when I open the work tab to set job priorities, some of the boxes are outlined in red for some workers. What does that mean? I know that the lightness of the box indicates sill level and flames are (faintly) shown to indicate passion. But I couldn't figure out what the red outline meant.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the work tab in question?

Comment: It could be that this worker can't do this job for various reasons like if he's scared of fire, he can't be a fire fighter or if he is missing both arms, he can't carry thing, I comment because I can't verify this right now

Comment: I can't get you a screenshot right now, but I'll try to remember to grab one tonight. As I remember, it was a red outline around the box where you enter a 1-4 priority for a work type. It was never all the boxes in a given column, but sometimes more than one. Some colonists would have more than one red box, some none at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The red outline indicates that the pawn assigned to that work has a skill level between 0-3. It's supposed to draw attention to the fact that there may be better pawns available to handle that type of work. Changing the priority on a red-boxed skill like this from 0 (unassigned) to 1-4 should also be accompanied by a "crunching" sound.

Sources:

[Official Wiki](https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Menus#Work)

[Developer response](https://ludeon.com/forums/index.php?topic=32749.0)